# python saving lists to files

Tags: python, list, load, pickle

When using

```
with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump([player], f, protocol=2)
```

to save a list and then try to open it it works, but when i use this code it gives me an error:

```
open("KappaClickerSave.json", "rb")
with open("KappaClickerSave.json", "rb") as f:

    savefile = pickle.load(f)
    house1 = savefile [0]
    house2 = savefile [1]
    house3 = savefile [2]
    house4=savefile [3]
```

`house2 = savefile [1]
IndexError: list index out of range` and I have 10 things in the list. Note that my 10 items in the list are all put in the list using `append`

EDIT: This is also the saving part about my save function:

```
open('KappaClickerSave.json', 'wb')
with open('KappaClickerSave.json', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump([savefile], f, protocol=2)
```

all appends were on the rows before that

EDIT 2: Here's ALL my code that is about saving:

```
import json
import pickle
```

**15 rows later...**

(This loads all houses)

```
open("KappaClickerSave.json", "rb")
with open("KappaClickerSave.json", "rb") as f:
    savefile = pickle.load(f)
    house = savefile [0]
    house2 = savefile [1]
    house3 = savefile [2]
    house4=savefile [3]
    house5=savefile [4]
    house6=savefile [5]
    house7=savefile [6]
    house8=savefile[7]
    house9=savefile[8]
    house10=savefile[9]
    house11=savefile [10]
    house12= savefile [11]
    house13= savefile [12]
    house14= savefile [13]
```

**50 rows later...**

(This adds all of the house numbers to the list)

```
def save():

    savefile = []
    savefile.append(house1)
    savefile.append(house2)
    savefile.append(house3)
    savefile.append(house4)
    savefile.append(house5)
    savefile.append(house6)
    savefile.append(house7)
    savefile.append(house8)
    savefile.append(house9)
    savefile.append(house10)
    savefile.append(house11)
    savefile.append(house12)
    savefile.append(house13)
    savefile.append(house14)
    open('KappaClickerSave.json', 'wb')
    with open('KappaClickerSave.json', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(savefile, f, protocol=2)
```

EDIT 3: just in case it matters, here is the code that gets written in my savefile:

€]q ]q(G        G@>      G        G@$      G        G@I      G        G?ð      G@o@     G        G        G@@     GA.„€    G        ea.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving a list with **one** element:

```
with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump([player], f, protocol=2)
```

If **after** this code you `append` elements to the list, the changes **will not** be reflected in the file. You should pickle the final result only.

So, change your code to:

```
my_list = [player]
my_list.append(1) 
# do all the appends
# at the end:
with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(my_list, f, protocol=2)
```

Comment: @Adde21_30 Your edit doesn't change anything. You are **still** saving only one-element lists and thus it's obvious that they don't have a  second element. Please provide *the whole code*, or at least something that show the exact logic from creating the lists to saving and loading them.

Comment: @Adde21_30 I think you could fix your error by simply changing `dump([savefile], ...)` to `dump(savefile, ...)`.

Comment: That was my code originally, but since that didn't work I changed it

Comment: @Adde21_30 To make it clear: you can have a list `savefile` with how many elements you want, but `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps([savefile]))` will **always** have only one element, because the `load` is *not* loading the `savefile` list but the list `[savefile]` which is a one-element whose only element is the `savefile` list. I cannot tell you anything more than this. If you still cannot make your code work you **must** post **the whole code** you are using.

Comment: I tried changing it but it gave me the same result, and since the whole code would NEVER fit in I am onl going to do erything that has with loading and saving to do

Comment: @Adde21_30 I cannot reproduce your problem, the type of code you have shown works fine for me. You should try to strip down your code to the minimum piece that reproduces the problem and post that, so that people can run that code and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok, somehow I don't get the error anymore (don't know why) but saving doesn't work. Do I have to empty the file of it's contents to save again?

Comment: NVM, the save works now. I just needed to change somethings with my buttons in tkinter. Thanks for the help